# What are good strategies to debug iOS apps with 'dangling UIViews'?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I recently inherited maintenance of a relatively small iOS application. The app was created by external contractors with very little guidance and oversight. Needless to say it needs "a little" cleaning - I am evaluating whether to redo the entire thing or not.

One thing that got me stumped is a crash in the app whereby the debugger shows "Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch".  In the module where this occurs, I researched all UIViews to make sure they are created with a parent (addSubView sets the root view controller, right?) - this seems all prim and proper.

Being rather new to XCode, I am not familiar with facilities that help me figure out what might be going on here. E.g., how can I quickly see/investigate the status of all UIViews created by a module?  How can I 'watch' a variable just to be alerted when it changes?  And in general, is there a best strategy to use to tackle issues like the one I described above?

Sorry to stay a bit vague but I don't think that publishing a bunch of ugly code helps you to understand the problem better :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular problem happens when the application's UIWindow doesn't have a value for its `rootViewController` property by the time it finishes launching. Take a look in your application delegate file - usually, the root view controller is set on the window there.

With regards to your more general questions: there are a variety of ways to inspect the state of your program as it runs. A very basic way to dump some info is to use an `NSLog` statement - you can print out messages to the console in much the same way as a C `printf` would. You can also set breakpoints in your application and use the debugger to inspect different variables - take a look at the lldb documentation for more info.

Comment: To expand on this slightly: before iOS 4 you just added your root controller to the window and forgot about it. Since 4 you're meant to set the `rootViewController` property explicitly. Either your contract work took place a while ago or your contract workers were extremely reckless in ignoring API changes and ignoring runtime warnings.

Comment: @Tommy I was able to get the issue solved pretty quickly by setting window.rootViewController in the appDelegate.  Yes, 'reckless' seems the appropriate term for what they were doing ;-(

Comment: @Tim, Thanks for your answer, I had hoped that XCode had something better than NSLog. However versatile that little function is, it seems XCode's debugging functions need a bit of an update, bummer. Oh well, now I know not to look for anything better...

Comment: @Yohst: You might be happier with breakpoints - there's quite a variety of options there, including the ability to log a message, evaluate expressions, and even skip breakpoints conditionally if you like. You can get pretty creative, and on recent versions of Xcode, the built-in debugger (lldb) is very scriptable and extensible as well.

Comment: @Tim, thanks for the suggestions, I'll study the break point options a bit more. Where can I find info on lldb scriptability?

Comment: @Yohst: take a look at the [LLDB Python reference](http://lldb.llvm.org/python-reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Whether you have "dangling" UIViews or not has not much to do with having a root view controller or not.

Instead, you should make sure that your app's [`UIWindow`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html) has a `rootViewController` at the end of your app delegates `appDidFinishLaunching` method.